# @Autowired works in an abstract class

Tags: spring, abstract-class

Hy,

How @Autowired works in an attribute declared in an abstract class if its not inherited in the subclasses. What spring does under the hood in order the subclasses have the dependency injected in them if @Autowired annotation is not inherited in the subclasses?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a *not inherited field in subclasses in Java*. The private fields get inherited just as any other non-static field, they're just not visible in the subclass code. They can still be accessed with reflection though. Spring will have no problem autowiring such fields.